# Is it okay to ignore the error notices I get on a Drupal site?

Tags: 7

My Drupal 7 site has many error notices like

> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 225 of
>   305 bytes in variable_initialize() (line 943 of
>   /site/includes/bootstrap.inc).

or

> Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in drupal_load() in bootstrap.inc

The site still works inspite of the errors. Is it okay to ignore these error notices?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: do you get this errors on production site?

Comment: FWIW, the `unserialize()` error likely means you have a bad value in the `{variables}` table.  That may or may not be serious.

Comment: The second error means that you have PHP code like this one somewhere: `some_function(&$variable)`. Possibly in a contributed or custom module.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3.8.

Comment: I get these errors on my production site.

Answer (score 3):

Between the two errors, the first is more worrying.

As [variable_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) passes the variables value it receives to `serialize()`, if `unserialize()` is not able to understand the saved data, it means the database content is probably corrupted. [variable_initialize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_initialize/7) calls `unserialize()` using the following code.

```
  // Proceed with variable rebuild.
  $variables = array_map('unserialize', db_query('SELECT name, value FROM {variable}')->fetchAllKeyed());
  cache_set('variables', $variables, 'cache_bootstrap');
  lock_release($name);
```

The second error says the code is using a feature that is deprecated, which means that in future PHP versions the code could not work anymore, but in the actual PHP version is still working.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's okay to ignore *certain* error notices. I usually google them up, first - with full text, then stripping the lines number. If I get a bunch of results pointing to other users' claims, I can then get the idea of what is going on, and sometimes - get a confirmation there's nothing I can do about that.

I used to have many bootstrap.inc errors before I learned to always do module updates one by one, rather than en masse, and always follow each by visiting /update.php to let the hooks pick up necessary database updates.